# After attaching the source to the customer object, how do I check from the customer object?

Tags: stripe-payments

```
$customer1 = \Stripe\Customer::create([
    "description" => "test",
    'email' => 'a@example.com',
]);
$customerObj = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer1->id);
$sourceObj = $customer->sources->create(["source" => 'src_xxxx']);
```

---

The source object has been created. I can understand this.

I can not understand where in the Customer object the source object was created.

How can I check the source object created above from the Customer object?

```
var_export($customer->sources->source);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to fetch the Customer object again to see the updated source in the list of sources. Use https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_customer for this